# my css grid boxes are not equal width due to the text within

Tags: html, css, css-grid

Hello my grid boxes are not equal depending on the text input i.e. if i inserted a number in each box the width will be equal however having different word-lengths makes the widths of each box not equal. Please help

```css
/*Grid Buttons*/

.grid-container {
  width: auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-right: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  padding-top: 30px;
}

.grid-item {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border-image-width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  height: 180px;
}

.grid-item img {
  display: inline-block;
  background-size: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-item">Workshops</div>
  <div class="grid-item">Classes</div>
  <div class="grid-item">Out Of School</div>
  <div class="grid-item">Our Teachers</div>
  <div class="grid-item">Our Kids</div>
  <div class="grid-item">Twinkle Parties</div>
```

Comment: Please post your code here so we can help (a minimal example of your grid would be okay, if it reproduces the behavior).

Comment: sorry i did not realise. https://jsfiddle.net/kayyoung/4Le7r8y0/2/

Answer (score 3):

You need to replace `grid-template-columns: auto auto auto` with `grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr`

Check out the MDN documentation for more information on [grid-template-columns](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-columns).

```css
/*Grid Buttons*/

.grid-container {
  width: auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-right: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  padding-top: 30px;
}

.grid-item {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border-image-width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  height: 180px;
}

.grid-item img {
  display: inline-block;
  background-size: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-item">Workshops</div>
  <div class="grid-item">Classes</div>
  <div class="grid-item">Out Of School</div>
  <div class="grid-item">Our Teachers</div>
  <div class="grid-item">Our Kids</div>
  <div class="grid-item">Twinkle Parties</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The first part of the solution is this:

```
.grid-container {
    ...
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr); /*same as: 1fr 1fr 1fr)/*
    ...
}
```

This alone however will not solve the real issue: a grid column will have a minimum width determined by the widest content in the column. This means that as soon as the content of a grid item becomes wider than the calculated width for the column, which the grid item is part of, the column will remain at least as wide as this wide content requires.
This can happen if e.g. the data for the grid is provided dynamically from a server or the grid container is set to be less wide on a small device.

In order to address this you could use the `minmax(min, max)` function to set a minimum and a maximum width for the grid columns like this:

```
.grid-container {
    ...
   /*I am using 0 as the minimum here, but you could also set something like 50px*/
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, minmax(0, 1fr)); /*same as: minmax(0, 1fr) minmax(0, 1fr) minmax(0, 1fr)*/
    ...
}
```

Depending on the minimum value you use and the actual width of the content you will have to make sure your text is not flowing outside of your grid items if becoming too long to fit inside.

I suggest wrapping your text in some tag e.g. `<span>` and set overflow behavior for this tag, like this:

`HTML`

```
<div class="grid-container">
    <div class="grid-item"><span>Workshops</span></div>
    <div class="grid-item"><span>Classes</span></div>
    <div class="grid-item"><span>Out Of School</span></div>  
    <div class="grid-item"><span>Our Teachers</span></div>
    <div class="grid-item"><span>Our Kids</span></div>
    <div class="grid-item"><span>Twinkle Parties</span></div>
</div>
```

`CSS`

```
.grid-item span {
    display: block;
    white-space: nowrap; /*you can leave this out if you want to allow line break*/
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use this in your CSS:

```css
.grid-container {
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the framework bootstrap instead to avoid creating boring css named "cards". You can find them [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/card/) and you can use it like that :

```
<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
  <img class="card-img-top" src="..." alt="Card image cap">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
  </div>
</div>
```